# why free(pointer) is giving runtime error?

Tags: c, malloc, runtime-error, free

I have below C program. It asks for number of coordinates from user. Then uses a malloc to allocate memory, stores the coordinates (integers) in the allocated memory, and then later frees the memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) /* Arguments to main() not necessary but used to keep with convention.*/
{
    int num_of_coordinates;
    printf("How many co-ordinates: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_coordinates);

    int *coordinate_array = malloc(num_of_coordinates * 2);
    int i, j;

    /* Below for loop takes the x and y coordinate of all points. */
    /* These coordinates are stored in coordinate_aaray[]. */
    for (i=0; i < num_of_coordinates*2; i++)
    {
            j = (i / 2) + 1 ;
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                    printf("Enter x coordinate of point %d: ",j);
                    scanf("%d",&coordinate_array[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                    printf("Enter y-coordinate of point %d: ",j);
                    scanf("%d",&coordinate_array[i]);
            }
    }

    for (i=0; i < num_of_coordinates*2; i++)
    {
            printf("%d ",coordinate_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Free the allocated memory. */
    free (coordinate_array);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run these program I get no issues till `number_of_coordinates` is equal or less than 3.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
How many co-ordinates: 3
Enter y-coordinate of point 1: 1
Enter x coordinate of point 1: 2
Enter y-coordinate of point 2: 3
Enter x coordinate of point 2: 4
Enter y-coordinate of point 3: 5
Enter x coordinate of point 3: 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
-bash-4.1$
```

However when I give `num_of_coordinates` a value of 4 or more I get a runtime error (most probably because of `free(coordinate_array)`).

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
How many co-ordinates: 4
Enter y-coordinate of point 1: 1
Enter x coordinate of point 1: 2
Enter y-coordinate of point 2: 3
Enter x coordinate of point 2: 4
Enter y-coordinate of point 3: 5
Enter x coordinate of point 3: 6
Enter y-coordinate of point 4: 7
Enter x coordinate of point 4: 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast):    0x000000000185b010 ***
```

Actually the runtime error message is a long one, so I just showed the first line of that error.

Why is this error happening when `num_of_coordinates`greater or equal to 4 in this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: `malloc(num_of_coordinates * 2 * sizeof(int))`  <==== something added here. Your program is exceeding the allocated boundaries of your sequence because you neglected to account for the size of each element, and in so doing, invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: always check the returned value from scanf (and family) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @ WhozCraig Dman ! How could I make this mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @1Byn unless you're a stickler for performance, for sequence allocations like this [**`calloc`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) is a decent option, as you are forced to specify both the number of elements **and** the size of each element as arguments. Just fyi.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for suggestion. Will read man page for `calloc`

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the call to free().  The problem is the code is writing beyond the allocated memory area.  resulting in undefined behaviour (it corrupted the overhead info in the heap) which can/will result in a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a number of problems with this line:

```
int *coordinate_array = malloc(num_of_coordinates * 2);

1) the amount of allocated memory is 1byte * num_of_coordinates * 2
That is not large enough to hold num_of_coordinates*2 integers
use:

int *coordinate_array = malloc(num_of_coordinates * 2 * sizeof int);

2) always check the returned value from malloc (and family) 
   to assure the operation was successful

int *coordinate_array = NULL;

if( NULL == (coordinate_array = malloc(num_of_coordinates * 2 * sizeof int) ) )
{ // then, malloc failed
    perror( "malloc for coordinate array failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful
```

Comment: `sizeof int` should be `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @user3629249 Will check the returned value of malloc in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had made a silly mistake.

I had allocated insufficient amount of memory using below statement.

```
int *coordinate_array = malloc(num_of_coordinates * 2);
```

However as each number is an `int` I had to use below statement.

```
int *coordinate_array = malloc(num_of_coordinates * 2 * sizeof(int));
```

After making this change, the program works with no runtime errors.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
How many co-ordinates: 4
Enter y-coordinate of point 1: 1
Enter x coordinate of point 1: 2
Enter y-coordinate of point 2: 3
Enter x coordinate of point 2: 4
Enter y-coordinate of point 3: 5
Enter x coordinate of point 3: 6
Enter y-coordinate of point 4: 7
Enter x coordinate of point 4: 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
-bash-4.1$
```

Comment: The program will produce lots of runtime errors if any call to scanf() or malloc() fails.   Always check the returned value from those calls to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to allocate the exact number of bytes required. As another user mentioned above you should use:

malloc(num_of_coordinates * sizeof(int) * 2)

Also, just to double check, how about you log values to test your code. For instance, log the num_of_coordinates to make sure that you scanned the right value.

To debug, you can try something like this: http://dmalloc.com/